# Could not Able to start my genesis block "Fatal: Account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden!"

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, dapps

I am getting some problem while i am trying to mine for my genesis block on my Geth command prompt **"Fatal: Account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden!"** could anyone please provide me help in this, i have tried this many times but getting this same error each time.....[image]

Comment: What's your full command line ?

Comment: My command line is WIndows powershell on that i am using geth commands.

Comment: My command is "atom startnode.cmd"

then after another command is ".\startnode.cmd"  after this command i am getting this error......

Comment: I was talking about the geth command.

Comment: i am not getting your words, could you please elaborate ......